# Handling update if record exists otherwise insert

Tags: java, sql-server

I have to update some fields in the record if it exists, otherwise insert a new record. The database used is SQL Server and is using Spring JdbcTemplate. My first draft is:

1. execute a select query to retrieve the record
2. if the record exists, update the fields and then execute an update query to update the record
3. if the record does not exist, execute an insert query to add a new record

```
Model m = modelDao.findByUserId(userId);

if (m != null) {
    m.setFieldA(updatedValue);
    modelDao.update(m);
} else {
    Model m = new Model();
    m.setFieldA(updatedValue);
    modelDao.add(m);
}
```

I wonder if this is the proper way to do, or it should be done in some other way? I see in MySQL there is something like `insert on duplicate key update`, but I'm using SQL Server, and I wonder what's the advantages of doing it via SQL instead of handling it in the code such as the above?

Comment: Its very much a matter of person choice whether you do this in code or in SQL.

Comment: @DaleK Not really.  The OP is using JPA, so as to be SQL dialect agnostic.  Generally, doing this for a specific SQL dialect is _not_ desirable, because then it means that the Java program would be tightly coupled to a particular SQL database.

Comment: The name for the operation you want to do is _upsert_, by the way.

Comment: Commonly called *upsert*, while the SQL standard calls it [*MERGE*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)).

Comment: If your Dao class can work with just userId and the updated field value then you could avoid find/select step by running update first and do the insert only when number of rows updated count was zero. This cuts down db accesses if update is the most frequent action.